# Using Jquerys toggle to change 'display: none' to show. Causes contents to be squashed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this:

```
<div class="sub-slider" style="display: none;">
    <section class="subscriptions_slider container-fluid">
        <?php echo do_shortcode("[subscriptions_slider]"); ?>
    </section>
</div>
```

And using Jquery like this:

```
$('.change-sub').on('click', function() {
    $('.sub-slider').toggle();
});
```

If I load the page now and click on `change-sub` button. The content that is toggle is squished. **But** if I load the page without `style="display: none;"` then it shows normally. Why is this?

Comment: Provide a sample content to understand how it is squished? Secondly, where is `change-sub` in your HTML?

Comment: @MilanChheda The content in this example is a php plugin which shows a subscription slider. Not sure how to show it. I think it has something to do with the display selector getting the wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

This is because display: none property will remove the element from the DOM,

If you dont want the element to get removed from DOM rather use VISIBILITY:HIDDEN, It will reserve the space for the container.

Something like below.

```
<div class="sub-slider" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <section class="subscriptions_slider container-fluid">
        <?php echo do_shortcode("[subscriptions_slider]"); ?>
    </section>
</div>
```

and

```
$('.change-sub').on('click', function() {
    var visibilityProp =  $('.sub-slider').attr('visibility');
    if(visibilityProp == 'hidden')
    {
        $('.sub-slider').attr('visibility','visible')
    }
    else
    {
        $('.sub-slider').attr('visibility','hidden');
    }   
});
```

**please mark it as answer if it is as per your need.**

Comment: Thanks, this fixes my squshied bug. But, why i use `display: none;` is because i dont want a big white-space area. Why does `display` cause this error?

Comment: This is the behaviour of display property of html, Still you can play with the property like, ON the page load use visibility property and then use display property. Kindly mark my solution as answer if it resolves your problem.

Comment: typo: `('visibility':'visible')` must be `('visibility','visible')` or `({'visibility':'visible'})`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, updated my answer, APology for typo.